# Running Batch File Upon Logging in

Tags: exception, proxy, batch-file, sleep

First of all I'm using Vista as my OS.
Second, I'm using Google Chrome as my browser, and a while ago it started removing my exceptions list in the advanced connection settings. Every time I add an exception, it gets removed a while after that. So I understood that I should write a batch file to open a registry key that I have created to initialize my proxy settings. The problem is, I always put my computer to sleep. and I want it to automatically get re-initialized each time I log in. BTW, I don't think I ACTUALLY log in when I come back from sleep mode. I'm guessing it's like locking the account.

So first, if you have a better solution to the exception problem.
Second, how can I write the batch file to run the registry key each time I come back from sleep

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to running something on user login, use the scheduled task, just create a task with this option and there run your script.

To automatically add you registry settings, just first save them on a file from the regedit program (find them, right click, and then save), later just add this file to the registery again by using a bat file that just add it using the regedit.

Comment: I've succeeded in scheduling the task, but the problem is that although the batch runs, it does not do what it's supposed to. Although when I run the batch manually it works. Also, when I unlock my account, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: Another thing, while I was trying it out I created multiple batch files, but now I can not delete them for some reason. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @MC1 maybe you can not delete because they still 'running', check on the shedule task that you do not use the GUI to run them.